# 3D editor library/API which is high-level with fast development time

Tags: library, api, 3d, opengl

Currently I'm developing a **high-performance** 3D editor shown by the following screen-shot. When I say high-performance, I mean that the 3D editor should be capable of handling STL files, several GB in size.

I'm using OpenGL for development. The problems with OpenGL is being **low-level** and consequently **slowing down** the development.

[image: Our 3dpe]

---

I'm afraid there might be any high-performance **commercial** or free/open-source library/API which I'm not aware of. Is there any high-performance library/API which can speed up the development of a 3D editor like mine? So far, I've found [Qt3D module](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2016/06/16/introducing-qt-3d/). Thanks.

---

I found a list [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_3D_graphics_libraries).

Comment: What do you mean by "high level"? What operations do you need, and which do you not need?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul High level in [this context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_3D_graphics_libraries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This repository may help if you are comfortable with C++ and Qt:

https://github.com/qt-labs/qt3d-editor

Comment: Can you point out the main features of the proposed program?

Comment: @Alejandro Undo/redo, import, select, delete, rotate/scale/translate, camera, ... basically anything you would expect of a basic 3D editor.

Comment: @Alejandro By the way, you can run it and check out the features. Out-of-the-box, it can be built and run with older versions of Qt.